# use a jquery selector where the attribute matches an id

Tags: jquery

I assign a lot of id's like this:

```
$(".split").each(function(index) {
       $(this).attr("id", index);
 });
```

Then later down the road i try a selector like this:

```
$("#id="+c)
```

But it throws the following error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #id=1
```

How can i select a id with a specific number?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: An offside note is when using numeric `id`, you won't be able to use the id selector in CSS, although it's still OK in script code.

Comment: Remember that a valid `id` cannot start with (or therefore be) a number.

Comment: @iblamefish -- HTML5 spec says ID's can start with a number

Comment: They can start with a number, they only have to be escaped: `document.querySelectorAll('#\\31')` gets `id` = `1`. `#1` works in jQuery because Sizzle "optimizes" it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need the `#` sign:

```
$("#" + number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the ID selector with this:

`$("#" + c)`

In other words, drop the `id=` in your expression because the correct way to select the ID of an element is to prefix it with a hash sign (#).

But I would advise against using a number as the ID of an HTML element, <strike>as this is an invalid CSS selector.</strike> My suggestion is to prefix it with a valid identifier to make more sense of the rendered HTML, assuming you're creating unique IDs from, say, list of items retrieved dynamically from a service. For example,

```
$(".split").each(function(index) {
   $(this).attr("id", "row_" + index.toString());
});
```

Then you would select as follows:

```
$("#row_" + c)
```

For, say, elements that look like this (ignore the fact I'm using DIVs):

```
   <div id="row_0">...</div>
   <div id="row_1">...</div>
   <div id="row_2">...</div>
   <div id="row_3">...</div>
   <div id="row_4">...</div>
```

**UPDATE:** I had originally said that numbers were invalid CSS selectors. @acdcjunior below posted a link that invalidated my original claim. My point is that you should avoid naming items with numbers because:

1. They don't make your code readable.
2. IDs must be unique for an entire HTML document. If you have another section within your HTML document that also names repeating items with numbers, you will run into naming collisions. In that case, prefix them, as described above, so they make sense within the context where they're used.

Comment: [Using only-number ids is valid HTML5.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). `#1` is an invalid CSS Selector, yes, but it can be escaped as `#\31` and Sizzle/jQuery supports `#1`. So your point at *as this is an invalid CSS selector* is, at best, innacurate.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But for the sake of readability, I stand  by original statement that it's not a good idea to use numbers to name things. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: There's no problem in suggesting not using number-only IDs. What I think it is important to notice is that you are not suggesting, you are saying numbers are invalid identifier, that does not mean your answer is lost, as it has other merits, but that specific bit of info is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

try below code :-

$("#" + data);

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Joeytje50 Please don't be so quick in judging. This is a correct answer.

Comment: @hvd Okay, I'm sorry about the given reason, but this answer does look more like a comment than an answer. An answer, especially when the answerer has 25 minutes time, should really have a further explanation than 'try this please'. When you say 'try this', you're asking the asker to do something and see if that works, while an answer generally is something that simply says 'this is the solution.' - While the reason is indeed not perfectly applicable to this situation, I do still think this answer is just a comment, not a complete answer.

Comment: @Joeytje50 Sure, that's a fair comment. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: well the person just below me has given same answer why no comments on his ans then?? @joeytje50